# caffe lstm layer doesn't work

Tags: c++, caffe

I want to train a model (VGG+LSTM) for doing Re-identification task in a video sequence. The main problem of my code is that, after I trained the model, I want to do the inference, but it seems like LSTM doesn't work. (I input a picture 9 times continually to the model, but every time it came out the same vector after lstm, so I believe there is something wrong).

Hear is my [train.prototxt](https://github.com/zhangfuyang/stuff/blob/master/train.prototxt). Briefly speaking, my `lstm` layer is

```
layer {
    name: "lstm"
    type: "LSTM"
    bottom: "Appearance_reshape"
    bottom: "cont"
    top: "lstm_out"
    recurrent_param {
    num_output: 128
        weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian"
        std: 0.005
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0.1
        }
    }
}
```

The bottom `"Appearance_reshape"` shape is 9*1*500, and `cont` shape is 9*1. and the value of `cont` is (0,1,1,...,1), means the sequence length is 9.

And here is my [lstm_deploy.prototxt](https://github.com/zhangfuyang/stuff/blob/master/lstm_deploy.prototxt). Briefly speaking, the important layers are as follow.

```
layer {
    bottom: "fc7"
    top: "Appearance_vector"
    name: "Appearance_vector"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 500
    }
}
layer {
    bottom: "Appearance_vector"
    top: "Appearance_vector"
    name: "Appearance_vector_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}
layer {
    name: "reshape"
    type: "Reshape"
    bottom: "Appearance_vector"
    top: "Appearance_reshape"
    reshape_param {
        shape: { dim: 0 dim: 1 dim: -1 }
    }
}
layer {
    name: "lstm"
    type: "LSTM"
    bottom: "Appearance_reshape"
    bottom: "cont"
    top: "lstm_out"
    recurrent_param {
        num_output: 128
    }
}
layer {
    name: "flatten"
    type: "Flatten"
    bottom: "lstm_out"
    top: "lstm_Y_flatten"
}
```

The output layer is `"flatten"`.

The source of test [inferance.cpp](https://github.com/zhangfuyang/stuff/blob/master/inferance.cpp), I am sorry that this code is really ugly :(

However, as you can see, I push back the same image to the input vector and calculate `lstm_vector`.

```
for(int i = 1; i < imgs.size(); i++) {
    tmp_img1.push_back(imgs[1]);
}
lstm_vector = model_lstm_net.calc(tmp_img1);
```

The problem is all the vectors came out from the model are same, but in my opinion, after using lstm layer, there maybe some difference between each output. Is there something wrong with the code, or just the training data was not good enough and caused nothing learned inside lstm layer?

I am really grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the values in the `cont` layer are incorrect, but it's hard to tell without knowing the entries in your label data before slicing.

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://github.com/CorvusCorax/Caffe-LSTM-Mini-Tutorial).

`cont` (called `clipmask` in the tutorial) needs to be **zero** for the first entry in each sequence and **one** for each subsequent entry. Whenever `cont` is zero, the LSTM layer forgets its memory and resets it to the initial value.

At the same time, LSTM retains its memory over multiple subsequent solver steps (forward/backward cycles), so the first entry in each timeseries MUST have it set to zero.